# Is there any way to make when opening a profile in Terminator automatically execute "ssh ip"

Tags: command-line, customization, terminator

Is there any way to make when opening a profile in Terminator automatically execute  ssh IP ?

I set

```
"use_custom_command = True"

" custom_command = sudo ssh 192.168.1.20"
```

but didn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "no work"? what happens, exactly? is an error message shown when the terminal opens?

Comment: When I select the profile, although it changes to the new profile (colors, font size, etc) but the command does not appear the promp. As is the case with the terminal that comes with by default in Ubuntu, I set an ssh in each profile when opening the profile appears in the promp "sudo ssh www23" Sorry, my English

Answer (score 0):

resolved

> nano  ~/.config/terminator/config

add

```
[[www20]]
 use_custom_command = True
 exit_action = restart
 custom_command = ssh  user@192.168.1.23;
```

Then run at console

```
terminator   -p www20
```

This open terminal con promp for ssh at www20